# Is it true that one Storage Entity Property can only be mapped to one Class Entity Property in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

Just trying to getting confirmation on: "Is it true that one Storage Entity Property can only be mapped to one Class Entity Property in EF? "

In other words, a storage entity property can not be used by more than one class property.

In EF4 and EF5, is this true?

Huge thanks for any enlightenment on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I have now found that you can map Entity properties to the same table column multiple time for different entities. I am using TPH in Devart's Entity Developer to do this.